# Shared Data Persistence between Native Android and React Native

Tags: android, react-native

I am currently working on a React-Native app with some Native Android code. I have some local notification functionality that I've set up on the Android side of things, but I need it to share a data store with my React Native code.

I know this is a pretty strange use-case, but given some larger restrictions imposed on the project, I can't rely on existing libraries for notifications.

Is there a way for the javascript part of my app to share a local, persisted storage solution with my native Android code? I'd love to be able to use something as simple as `AsyncStorage` or `Realm` in React-Native, and simply be able to read/write to that same store in my Native code, but my initial google searches turned up nothing.

Is anyone familiar with doing this? Would appreciate any guidance or advice!

Comment: You could use the built-in SQLite installation and write your own RN wrapper for it

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want something like AsyncStorage, use below library to set and get data in **SharedPreferences**.

https://github.com/sriraman/react-native-shared-preferences

To set and get data in React Native Javascript, just import SharedPreferences and use it like this:

```
SharedPreferences.setItem("key_of_data","data to store"); 
SharedPreferences.getItem("key_of_data", function(value){   
// fetched data is accessible here 
});
```

To set and get data in Android Native:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences

```
SharedPreferences settings = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("wit_player_shared_preferences", getApplicationContext().MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Get data:

```
String dataToFetch = settings.getString("key_of_data", null);
```

Set data:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("key_of_data", "data to store");
editor.commit();
```

**Note**: For now you'll have to use this shared name only: "wit_player_shared_preferences"